# Not able to start the Ubuntu

Tags: boot, 18.04, kernel, 19.04

I upgraded my Ubuntu from 18.04 to 19.04, but when I'm starting the system, it isn't starting. Just a purple screen is showing up.
When I tried recovery mode, it shows a black screen with the following message:

```
[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0, 0) ] - - -
```

It's not giving options to type anything.

[image: black screen]

Comment: @galoget the mentioned answers in that post aren't working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution and now the system works fine.

1. Reboot the system by typing `reboot` command
2. Choose an **Ubuntu recovery mode** while startup
3. if a **faulty disk is shown in error messages** like /dev/sda1 or
   something, just run the command `fsck /dev/sda1 -y`, here /dev/sda1 is
   faulty disk in my system, you might have an error with some other
   disk. Now, your system will fix the disk and it will restart
   automatically, or you can manually restart once the process is
   finished.

Answer (score 5):

@https://askubuntu.com/users/730868/neeraj-bhatt
**I think you should remove old linux kernels because your /boot drive is out of space.**

Follow the steps as below :-

1) boot to grub and click on “**Advanced options**”
2) Select a previous kernel (should boot fine)
3) login and enter command
4) $ **df**
(See if your /boot directory is 100% used)
5) Remove old linux kernels
6) $ **sudo apt-get autoremove**

Comment: Note: This only applies to users with installations using LVM or full disk encryption. Other installations don't have a separate `/boot` partition, so don't need to worry about this case. ([source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels))

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do a soft reinstall.  make a live usb of 18.04 or 19.04 and choose the option to keep all your installed packages but reset config files.  Should be least painful way to solve imo.

Answer (score 0):

If this happened during a distribution upgrade of Ubuntu (19.04 to 19.10 in my case), it can be because packages are still left in a half-configured state.

In this case, boot the system in recovery mode using an older kernel. That will work. Then go to the root shell in recovery mode, and execute this to finish the interrupted installation process:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

Afterwards, execute `reboot`. The system hopefully starts again cleanly with the kernel installed with the new Ubuntu version.